# how to read the error of a callback function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, error-handling, callback

I am writing some code in order to call an api and get some data.... the code has a github repository https://github.com/kwiksand/yobit and I an calling one of the function/method called addTrade (under index.js)...

After passing API key and security, I have the following code:

```
  privateYoBit.addTrade(function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err)
    },"eth_btc","buy",0.04, 0.02);
  }
```

I get the following response:

```
{ success: 0, error: 'invalid method' }
null
```

My questions are:

1. console.log(err) return a "null value: does it means the code is ok and the problem is at the other end (the API)?
2. how do I debug/refine the "invalid method" return?

any help/support is much appreaciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Reading [source of the mentioned library](https://github.com/kwiksand/yobit/blob/master/index.js#L267), it looks like the author is sending along the following params as part of the request:

```
var params = {
    symbol: symbol,
    type: type,
    amount = amount,
    price = price
}
```

However, reading [the documentation for the API](https://www.yobit.net/en/api/#n23), they expect the following 4 parameters:

```
pair   : pair (example: ltc_btc)
type   : transaction type (example: buy РёР»Рё sell)
rate   : exchange rate for buying or selling (value: numeral)
amount : amount needed for buying or selling (value: numeral)
```

Maybe try adjusting the library to conform to the parameters the API expects?

If I were you, I would be really careful about using an untrusted, untested API to make trades...

Comment: I have worked with neither the Yobit API or this library, so I can only give some speculation. Try changing the parameter definitions in `index.js` to what the API expects? Change `params.symbol -> params.pair`, `params.price -> params.rate`

Comment: that makes sense... I am actually a newbie on node.js and trying to reverse engineer the library, so I can trust/modify it ;)

If I look at the parameters from the the Yobit website (API source), how should I do a call to initiate a trade? A bit confused on how to pass the authentication in the url... 

https://yobit.net/tapi/ ?????


[Authentication](https://www.yobit.net/en/api/#n21) 

thanks

Comment: Sorry, again, I've never used the Yobit API and at this point all I can do is the same as you, read the docs. Looks like with each request you need to pass your API key, and hash all of your post parameters via SHA512. This is what the section that you linked me states.